# Apache 2.2.15 + Wildfly 10 ajp

Tags: java, apache, wildfly, redhat

I'm working using apache as reverse proxy for wildfly v.10, the configuration is ok, ajp port in standalone.xml and http.d.conf are the same, also I have jboss v.7 and the same apache as reverse proxy running ok.

Hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: what is your question? you just told what you have not what is the problem